# Representing homological classes which are multiples of each other

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $N$ be a closed orientable $4$-manifold and $\alpha \in H_3(N)$. Then, we can find a three-dimensional submanifold $M$ of $N$ such that $\iota_\ast[M] = \alpha$ under the embedding $\iota: M \to N$.

Now, let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\beta = k \alpha$. Similary, there exists another 3-dimensional $M' \subset N$ with $\iota'_\ast[M'] = \beta$.

My stupid question: How are $M$ and $M'$ related?
Is $M'$ just the $k$-fold cover of $M$ (with changed orientation, perhaps), or does this somehow contradict that both are embedded in $N$?.

Answer (score 3):

For negative $k$ of course you have to change the orientation.  For positive $k$, you don't have to take the $k$-fold cover.  Representing $M$ as the level surface of a "Morse" function $f\colon N\to S^1$, one can just take $k$ nearby values of $f$ and take their union to represent the class $k\alpha$.  Or, if you want your hypersurface connected, just connect those components by thin tubes.

Comment: You take $k$ different preimages you mean and consider their disjoint union?

Comment: How do things change when $N$ is 6-dimensional? Then, of course, this argument does not work.

Comment: @warzasch , that's a diffent *question* :-)

Comment: You are absolutely right! Honestly, I did not very much care about dimension 4 here. I should have used dimension 6, 7 or 8 as ambient manifold, where the representability problem is solved positively still for each class, but no description is available of the dual cohomolog in terms of a map into some EM-space. How does this $M'$ in general look like.

Comment: Wait a minute, codimension one  homology classes can always be represented as level surfaces of a map to $S^1$ by Poincare duality and such things.

Comment: Btw: Is it granted that the preimage of the closeby values of $f$ are closeby to $M$? Or why do we have such thin tubes?

Comment: Locally the manifold is a product of $M$ by an interval, so Euclidean intuitions apply locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149312/discussion-between-warzasch-and-mikhail-katz).